# Keyboard source/layout (US English) in settings doesn't match with actual keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 on a laptop with a Swiss layout. When I plug in an external keyboard with a US layout and switch the Input Source to English (US), it doesn't seem to work as expected.

My keyboard is most definitely in US English QWERTY layout, as can be seen here: https://keyshorts.com/blogs/blog/44712961-how-to-identify-laptop-keyboard-localization

In the Ubuntu Settings under Language and Region / Input Sources, I can also show the keyboard layout selected and it matches my keyboard. However, when I press buttons, the output doesn't match what I'm pressing. For example, the 3/# key gives a £ instead when I shift click it, and the @ is on the '/" key instead. This seems to resemble a UK keyboard.

Is this a problem with my keyboard or else how could I fix this?

Comment: Try US International.

Comment: Same problem. Like I said the US English key layout should perfectly match my keyboard, even when you show the expected layout in the Ubuntu settings. Could the keyboard or driver itself have had something tweaked?

Comment: No, they can't. that does not depend on driver in any way. The problem is at the OS settings, user settings, etc.

Comment: I have a US keyboard as well. The correct setting I see in mine is English (US, intl., with dead keys). You or may not need the "dead keys", I do. It works perfectly.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I'm afraid that made it worse, basically Shift + 3, 4, 5 etc.. all give the wrong letter, and now instead of punctuation on the right side of my keyboard, I'm getting accented letters.

Comment: Here are the Shift + ... outputs for the numbers 1-6:
with English (US, intl., dead keys): +"*ç%&
with English (US): !"£$%^
neither of which match my keyboard, which should be: !@#$%^

Comment: The accented letters IS the reason for the "dead keys" - that I need but you may not -. Without dead keys it should be the English (US, alt. intl.). But to use the dead keys feature all you'd need to do is press space after the special character.